# Executing javascript code on all browsers but chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, browser

is it possible to execute a javascript code on all browser but not on chrome?

I tried looking for a code snippet everywhere, but i only found browser detection codes and was unable to work it together so the code will not get executed on chrome browsers :(

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

This is what i currently have, will this work?

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
<!--
var browserName=navigator.appName; 
if (browserName=="Google Chrome")
{ 

}
else 
{ 
 "the code for every other browser here"
   }
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Browser detection is the way to go. Show us what you tried? Have you opened the (chrome) console to see if there are any errors?

Comment: Just being curious: Why?

Comment: @RonPeyce What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: Why are you asking if it will work? Just run the code and you'll be able to see for yourself.

Comment: it doesn't work for me =(

Comment: @RonPeyce - Of course it won't work because `appName` is not supposed to return the name of the browser.

Comment: @Derek Don't use the question comments block just to advertise your answer.

Comment: @Jack Why would I want to advertise my answer?

Comment: To get more useful answers, it would be better to also highlight why you don't want certain code to run on Chrome browsers.

Answer (score 0):

[`appName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.appName) isn't helpful in this case since it will only return `"Netscape"` in most case. Use `appVersion` instead:

```
var isChrome = /Chrome/i.test(navigator.appVersion);
if(!isChrome){
    //stuff for non-Chrome
}
```

However, a user can easily override this value, resulting in an unreliable browser detection.

Comment: False positive on Edge.

Answer (score 0):

after running `console.log(window)` i noticed an object name chrome, i tried testing the other browsers for this object and it's undefined

### http://jsfiddle.net/aWqSt/1/

```
if(!window.chrome){
    alert("you are not using google chrome :(");
}else{
    alert("you are using google chrome");
}
```

you'll most likely be safe with Derek's or my example considering the user doesn't tamper with the request however to be more than sure the user is not using google chrome

### http://jsfiddle.net/aWqSt/2/

```
var isChrome = /Chrome/i.test(navigator.appVersion);
if(!window.chrome && !isChrome){
    alert("you are not using google chrome :(");
}else{
    alert("you are using google chrome");
}
```

Comment: @RonPeyce no problem, i would use my second example script to test for chrome as it really isn't that more demanding to double check and is more solid

Comment: yea i just tried it and if its more safe i will use that version. works perfect, just like i wanted it to! :)

Comment: False positive on Edge.